# Mongoid where clause ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, mongoid

Say I have a mongoid document which has a field `:pairs` with the type of hash. When I wan't to query on the hash like this:

```
Doc.where(:pairs=>{"field1"=>1})
```

I get results back because I have in pairs a field with value one. I also have values for more than `1`. When I do the following, `nil` is returned:

```
Doc.where(:pairs=>{"field1"=>{"$gt"=>0}})
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I do have pairs with key `field1` and values bigger than `0`. Can anyone provide me info on why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Just try: `Dco.where(:pairs.gt => 0)` 
For more detail mongoid querying see following link.
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html

Comment: @ganesh With that query you don't specify which hash key should has a value greater than 0, but all keys in the hash :pairs , so that will probably return more documents than expected. As another document with the hash :pairs can have a key field2 with value 0 and a field1 with value 2, your provided query will also return  this document, whilst as in my question it should not.

Answer (score -1):

```
Doc.where('pairs.field1' => {"$gt"=>1})
```

Comment: The OP is asking for values greater than 0.